# Language Identification Better Results with Unigrams

Tags: natural-language, naive-bayes, language-models, bag-of-words

I have a school project which consists of identifying each language of a tweet from a dataset of tweets. The dataset contains tweets in Spanish, Portuguese, English, Basque, Galician and Catalan. The task is to implement a language identification model using unigrams, bigrams and trigrams and to analyze the efficiency of each model.

I understand the concepts of ngrams and I understand that the languages are somewhat similar (hence it's not that trivial of a task), but what I don't understand is that I'm getting better results for unigrams than bigrams and I'm getting better results for bigrams than trigrams.

I can't comprehend how this is possible; I expected to find better efficiency for bigrams and trigrams.

Could you help me shed some light on why is this happening?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I assume that if your data set is not extremely large, counting of higher n-grams will lead to a worse estimate of the true frequency than lower ones, since there are too many combinations of very low probability. Therefore, many trigrams would not contain any useful information. Do you use any smoothing, or just plain empirical frequencies?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have implemented smoothing indeed. It does work much better. I also noticed a bug in my n-gram generation which made the model perform better than it used to.

Now, another thing I can't really understand is the fact that depending on the smoothing value I choose, the change in accuracy is quite significant in the sense that when I choose a very small smoothing value (e.g. 0.01), I get better results than when I choose a larger smoothing value (e.g. 1.00).